# Problem compiling from source OpenCV with MVSC2019 in 64 bit version

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I was compiling openCV for windows with Qt using MSVC in the 2019 64 bit version.

At the time of launching the first configuration I get a bit list of errors like this:

```
Check size of size_t
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/CheckTypeSize.cmake:147 (try_compile):
  Cannot copy output executable

    ''

  to destination specified by COPY_FILE:

    'C:/Users/alejandro/Downloads/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CheckTypeSize/SIZEOF_SIZE_T.bin'

  Recorded try_compile output location doesn't exist:

    C:/Users/alejandro/Downloads/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-jglvcw/Debug/cmTC_e9d0b.exe

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/CheckTypeSize.cmake:277 (__check_type_size_impl)
  3rdparty/libjpeg-turbo/CMakeLists.txt:25 (check_type_size)
```

Does anyone know how can I solve this problem?

**EDIT 1**

I have seen that another importar error is this one related with OpenMP:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake:420 (try_compile):
  Cannot copy output executable

    ''

  to destination specified by COPY_FILE:

    'C:/Users/alejandro/Downloads/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/FindOpenMP/ompver_C.bin'

  Recorded try_compile output location doesn't exist:

    C:/Users/alejandro/Downloads/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-q8quzk/Debug/cmTC_e2ecd.exe

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake:560 (_OPENMP_GET_SPEC_DATE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake:768 (find_package)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindLAPACK.cmake:247 (find_package)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindLAPACK.cmake:283 (_lapack_find_dependency)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLAPACK.cmake:176 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:733 (include)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, it is the CMake-3.25.0-rc2 fault, change it to 3.24.2 and it will work.

Comment: Does anybody know further about this? I've got a very similar issue with OpenCV 4.5.0 building using VS2017 and cmake 3.25.0. The issue seems to be new version of cmake.

Comment: OK seems that this is issue https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/22784 and the solution is to wait for cmake 3.25.1.